# How To Send Artist and Title Data to TuneIn API

Tags: vbscript, shoutcast, tunein

I am trying to use this script to send artist and title data to TuneIn Radio per their API, where I am getting lost is at this point:

```
Dim o
Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
o.open "GET", "http://air.radiotime.com/Playing.ashx?partnerId=<ID>&partnerKey=<key>&id=<station>&title=blank&artist=blank", False
o.send
```

The problem I run into is with pre-created variables in place as such

```
Function HandleLine(sLine)
  divisao = (sline)
  divisao = split(divisao,"-")

  SongInfo.Value("artist") = (Trim(divisao(0)))
  SongInfo.Value("title") = (Trim(divisao(1)))
  SongInfo.Value("songtype") = "S"

  SongInfo.DoSongChange
End Function
```

I want to be able to take these variables and use them in the URL Send string above to send to the API...Does anyone know how to make this possible?

If not, the file is originally read as a text file on a remote PC, and if variables could be created off that I could go there too.

Comment: Where does `SongInfo` come from, and how does the function `HandleLine` factor in the HTTP request? As for using variables in a string: that's an [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vbscript/info).

Comment: Hello Ansgar, SongInfo is a preset variable inside of the application that reads the text file, then splits it into as seen above

HandleLine technically does not factor into the HTTP Request, I can easily move it out of that function into its own, as I've seen success in basic testing with it

In essence, if there is a way to read the text file again in a separate function that can do the same as the current script but export via that HTTP String would be the method I seek

Answer (score 1):

Your question still isn't very clear to me, but assuming that you want to fill the URL parameters `title` and `artist` with the values from your `SongInfo` object you could do the following:

```
url = "http://air.radiotime.com/Playing.ashx" & _
      "?partnerId=<ID>&partnerKey=<key>&id=<station>" & _
      "&title=" & Replace(SongInfo.Value("title"), " ", "+") & _
      "&artist=" & Replace(SongInfo.Value("artist"), " ", "+")

Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
o.open "GET", url, False
o.send
```

Depending on what characters the values for `artist` and `title` contain you may need to encode them first:

```
Function Encode(ByVal str)
  Set re = New RegExp
  re.Pattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9_.~-]"

  enc = ""
  For i = 1 To Len(str)
    c = Mid(str, i, 1)
    If re.Test(c) Then c = "%" & Right("0" & Hex(Asc(c)), 2)
    enc = enc & c
  Next

  Encode = enc
End Function
```

Comment: Apologies for it not seeming clear still...let me see if I can better explain what I'm trying to achieve. 

Where "Title" and "Artist" show in the HTTP String, I want to take what is already gathered in the SongInfo Fields from the text file, and place it there, so it sends the data to TuneIn

And where there would normally be spaces in title and artist entries, needs to encode a + sign where said space would go.

Hope this makes a little more sense

Comment: @WayneOwens `Replace(SongInfo.Value("..."), " ", "+")`

Comment: What line would I place this in? I'm sorry I'm definitely not familiar with VBScript

Comment: @WayneOwens The `Replace` function returns the values with spaces replaced by plusses. Take a look at the code and ask yourself: where would you want the modified value(s)?

Comment: Maybe it's me playing dumb but I'm totally clueless here...literally...I could handle PHP and some Java but VB is way outta my ballpark, what I found originally was copied and pasted from a forum and prebuilt :(

Comment: @WayneOwens Then SO is not the right place for your question. We do expect you to have at least a basic understanding of how the language works that you're asking about (regardless of what language that is). I updated my answer, but don't expect further spoon-feeding.

Comment: Yeah for some reason it's not taking like it's supposed to, thank you for the assistance thus far...I'll check into a scripting service and see what a custom may cost